# From normal distribution to the lognormal distrubtion; where does $1/x$ come from?

Tags: normal-distribution

So the normal distribution is given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$; Now the lognormal distribution is related to this by $y = e^x$ so the distrbution should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln(y)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, but apparently it is $\frac{1}{\color{red}{y}\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln(y)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, so where does this $\frac{1}{\color{red}{y}}$?

It's apparent to me that this substitution is invalid, so the question is really: What's the valid way to do it?

Comment: Why is it that you think that if $X$ has density function $f(\cdot)$ and $Y = \phi(X)$ for some invertible function $\phi$ that $f(\phi^{-1}(y))$ should be a suitable probability density function for $Y$?

Comment: @Nadiels That was simply an assumption, which was demonstrably false. I was wondering _why_.

Comment: In a word, you forgot the Jacobian. Recall that when you make a substitution in a pdf, you need to preserve the appropriate probability masses (integrals of the density).

Comment: @FrankVel sorry if I sounded snarky, I guess I was asking what lead you towards that assumption because of when you wrote "so the distribution should be". Anyways for what it is worth I do think there is something to be said for the later answer you received, in particular the manipulation of the CDF at the start - I think it gives more insight rather than saying it is just a case of matching up the volume element

Comment: @MichaelHardy at the time it was the best answer. I see no reason to not update the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the chain rule.

You have $\log Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2),$ so
\begin{align}
& \Pr( Y \le y) = \Pr(\log Y \le \log y) = \Pr\left( \frac{(\log Y) - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{(\log y) - \mu}{\sigma} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^{((\log y) - \mu)/\sigma} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi\,}} e^{-z^2/2} \, dz,
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}
\frac d {dy} \Pr(Y \le y) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(((\log y) - \mu)/\sigma)^2/2} \cdot \frac d {dy} \, \frac{(\log y) -\mu} \sigma.
\end{align}

This is the chain rule, applied thus:
$$
\frac d {ds} \int_{\text{some number}}^{g(s)} h(w) \, dw = h(g(s)) \cdot \frac d {ds} g(s).
$$

**Alternatively,** one could do the following:
$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y\le y) & = \Pr( \log Y \le \log y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\log y} \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(w - \mu)/\sigma)^2/2} \, dw \\[10pt]
\text{and consequently } \frac d {dy} \Pr(Y \le y) & = \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-((\log y) - \mu)/\sigma)^2/2} \cdot \frac d {dy} \log y.
\end{align}
$$
The bottom line will be the same.

Comment: Ah, so the substitution can only be applied to the CDF, not the PDF. Is this always the case? And it seems to me that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}}\frac{\log(y)}{\sigma} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{1}{y}$, resulting in $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ in the final expression; $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ should perhaps be removed from the first term?

Comment: @FrankVel : I see I had a confusing typo; now I've fixed it. The density under the integral sign would be the standard normal density, so there's no $1/\sigma$ there. So there ends up being just one $1/\sigma,$ coming from  $(d/dy) (\log y)/\sigma. \qquad$

Comment: @FrankVel : I've now added a slightly different way. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Apply the following theorem, from [Requirements for transformation functions in probability theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399068/requirements-for-transformation-functions-in-probability-theory)

Let $X$ be an absolutely continuous random variable with support $S$ and probability density function $f(x)$. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be one-to-one and differentiable on $S$. If 
$$\frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy}  \ne 0, \qquad \forall y \in g(S)$$
then the probability density of $Y$ is 
$$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left|{\frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy}}\right|, \qquad \forall y \in g(S)$$

The term $\dfrac{1}{y}$ comes from $\left|{\dfrac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy}}\right|$, because in your case $g(x) = e^x$ and $g^{-1}(y) = \ln y$.